# Mapbox : Loading/Rendering 3D buildings at a large scale

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to display a 3D skyline/panoromic view of Manhattan using Mapbox yet with Mapbox GL extruded 3D buildings start to disappear below zoom level of 15. Is there a way to render/display them at zoom level around 11-12? Or an alternative way by clipping/filtering rendered/loaded data by mapbox?

I have tried to filter the map to the area of Manhattan and Roosevelt islands yet later found out it's not possible to clip/filter MapBox to a geographical area.

As the final result I'm hoping to render the buildings at the final view shown in the last image.

[image: 3D building extrusions zoom extent]
[image: display @ zoom level 15.12]
[image: display @ zoom level 14.87]
[image: final view]

Comment: did you ever find out? having the same problem now..

Comment: @dan I moved on from this project yet what I've heard is that you can do this with leaflet.. somehow I would check there